# TSQL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE T3
(
  DD DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

When start to insert rows to T3 via this:

```
INSERT T3 SELECT 1;
```

I get

```
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Why are the values in year 1900 ?

I am using sql server express 2012 . The clock on my machine is current .

Comment: What did you expect the behaviour of that statement was going to be? Trying to understand the thinking behind the `SELECT 1` in the first place.

Comment: erm what do you think default current_timestamp is meant to do?

Comment: why did I get -2 ? Did I do something against stackoverflow guidelines ?

Answer (score 4):

Your `INSERT T3` without an explicit column list will expect a source of values for the insert that contains a value for every column in the table except `IDENTITY`/`ROWVERSION` or computed columns.

Your table has a single such column and the `SELECT` statement source supplies one column. So the result is that you are inserting an explicit integer value `1` to column `DD`.

That column's datatype is `datetime` requiring an implicit cast. The result of `SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME)` is `1900-01-02` hence the results you see.

The legacy `datetime` datatypes allow implicit casts from `int` and `float` and treat the numeric values as days since `1900-01-01`. The newer datatypes such as `datetime2` do not support these implicit cast and would raise an error instead.

Default constraint values are only applied when you don't insert an explicit value for that column.

In your case you can do this either by

```
INSERT T3 DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Or

```
INSERT T3 (DD) VALUES (DEFAULT)
```

Comment: And "Day 0" in SQL Server is 1900-01-01 - thus inserting "1" results in 1900-01-02